# How to disable distraction free mode in code anaywhere

Tags: codeanywhere

Enabled distraction free mode in CodeAnywhere and have no idea how to turn it off again, since there's no menus or icons on the page. Anyone know the keyboard shortcut to get my menus back? :)

as you can see form the below screenshot, there are no buttons or anything else to click. Right clicking does nothing.. so kinda lost :)

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/jg07on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem.

You just need to hit `Shift + F11` to exit distraction free mode

Comment: Thanks @Swayam your a god send :)

Comment: No worries, I just tried sublime text's shortcut to exit distraction free mode and it magically worked. I suspect the editor has a similar if not the same keymap as sublime text

Comment: They should have mentioned it somewhere such people know how to disable it I see it in the dropdown, but I clicked it already. Bad UX. Had to come to stackoverflow for this.

Comment: not working....

Answer (score 0):

It was just `ESC` on Mac for anyone that needs to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can now search for Distraction and select Exit Distraction Free Mode. Alternatively, you can use ⌘⇧A (macOS), or Ctrl+Shift+A (Windows/Linux), to bring up the Find Actions dialog which will filter the Search Everywhere dialog to just Actions.
[Check this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tips/distraction-free-mode/)